# (Unity3D) I want to know if how can i download my videos located in the asset folder to android

Tags: unity-game-engine

If I click a button, the video that is located in my asset folder will be downloaded to the android storage. thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1):

Create a directory called StreamingAssets in your Asset folder, then everything you put inside will be kept as is.

Then you can retrieve it by using `Application.streamingAssetsPath + "pathOfWhatYouWant"`

Comment: Hi Jichael. i am new in unity and i dont have knowledge in c# can you please provide me a sample code? i appreciate ur help

Comment: @FrancisJayBedes  I understand that you are a beginner, but you were given a smudge in the right direction. If you expect to be spoon fed on every task you want to accomplish you won't get far in this field. You were given the answer on how to prepare the setup and the snippet of code that will retrieve the path to the assets. Now you need to go on and do your research on what are fairly common tasks like how to download (i.e. copy in your case) files in C#. You can find plenty of resources on the web about such common tasks. Good Luck!

Comment: I do apologize, thank you for you help. i'll research further so that i can learn in my own. thank you for your words  it helps me a lot. that i have to be independent enough to solve suach a problem. Thank you again and God Bless! 

Comment: @FrancisJayBedes And we will be happy to help you if you get stuck on a specific problem after you try on your own

Comment: im so stressed right now  my time is running out thats the only feature that i cant understand how to handle.